# Can't delete all records except first one

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete all records from a certain user except the first one, however I'm getting this error:

## 1093 - You can't specify target table 'History' for update in FROM clause

I don't understand what's the problem and also I found a similar question in SO that proposed this same solution. This is my query:

```
DELETE FROM `History` WHERE ID = '3' AND Date NOT IN (SELECT min(Date) FROM `History` WHERE ID = '3')
```

Comment: What is *your* SQL statement that you're executing?

Comment: it's the one in the end of the question. I realize it wasn't clear, I just edited it

Comment: I think you must have changed the query - since BotsHistory does not appear in the SQL.

Comment: botshistory is history, I changed it to make the question simpler and forgot about the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to solve this problem, by wrapping the subquery in another layer of a subquery.  MySQL generates the intermediate query, which prevents this error:

```
DELETE FROM `History`
    WHERE ID = '3' AND
           Date NOT IN (select mindate
                        from (SELECT min(Date) as mindate FROM `History` WHERE ID = '3')
                       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting it to `JOIN`

```
DELETE  a
FROM    History a
        LEFT JOIN History b
            ON a.Date = b.Date AND
                b.ID = 3
WHERE   b.date IS NULL AND
        a.ID = 3
```

*Before executing the statement above, please do backup the table first.*

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query once

```
  DELETE FROM `History` main WHERE main.ID = '3' 
      AND main.Date NOT IN 
           (SELECT min(inn.Date) FROM `History` WHERE main.ID = inn.id)
```